# custom legend ggplot2 / ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a series of graphs where I have manually coloured different bars. I would like to create a (ideally shared) legend which refers to the colour of the bars. The bar colours are not a property of the graph aesthetic, so I am not sure how to do this manually.

Below is some example code

```
set.seed(1234)
id <- rep(1:50, each = 3)
stimuli <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 1, times = 50)
dv_1 <- rnorm(150, mean = 2, sd = 0.7)
dv_2 <- rnorm(150, mean = 4, sd = 1.5)
dv_3 <- rnorm(150, mean = 7.5, sd = 1)


simdat <- data.frame(id, stimuli, dv_1, dv_2, dv_3)

#Stimuli A
dat_stimuli_a <- subset(simdat, stimuli == "a")

melt_a <- melt(dat_stimuli_a, id.vars = "id", measure.vars = c("dv_1", "dv_2", "dv_3"))

pwc_a <- melt_a %>%
  wilcox_test(value ~ variable, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "holm", detailed = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1:2)

pwc_a

gg_a <- ggplot(melt_a, aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", width = 0.75, aes(fill = variable)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="black", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc_a, label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.02, step.increase = 0.05, hide.ns = TRUE, y.position = c(7, 8), label.size = 3) +
  ggtitle("Stimuli A") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1), labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), limits = c(-0, 10)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=10)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25))

gg_a <- gg_a + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#9E0142", "#FDAE61", "#FDAE61")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")


#Stimuli B
dat_stimuli_b <- subset(simdat, stimuli == "b")

melt_b <- melt(dat_stimuli_b, id.vars = "id", measure.vars = c("dv_1", "dv_2", "dv_3"))

pwc_b <- melt_b %>%
  wilcox_test(value ~ variable, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "holm", detailed = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1, 3)
pwc_b

gg_b <- ggplot(melt_b, aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", width = 0.75, aes(fill = variable)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="black", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc_b, label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.02, step.increase = 0.05, hide.ns = TRUE, y.position = c(7, 8), label.size = 3) +
  ggtitle("Stimuli B") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1), labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), limits = c(-0, 10)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=10)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25))

gg_b <- gg_b + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FDAE61", "#9E0142", "#FDAE61")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")

#Stimuli C
dat_stimuli_c <- subset(simdat, stimuli == "c")

melt_c <- melt(dat_stimuli_c, id.vars = "id", measure.vars = c("dv_1", "dv_2", "dv_3"))

pwc_c <- melt_c %>%
  wilcox_test(value ~ variable, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "holm", detailed = TRUE) %>%
  slice(2:3)
pwc_c

gg_c <- ggplot(melt_c, aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", width = 0.75, aes(fill = variable)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="black", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc_c, label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.02, step.increase = 0.05, hide.ns = TRUE, y.position = c(8, 9), label.size = 3) +
  ggtitle("Stimuli C") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1), labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), limits = c(-0, 10)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=10)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25))

gg_c <- gg_c + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FDAE61", "#FDAE61", "#9E0142")) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")

figure <- ggarrange(gg_a, gg_b, gg_c, ncol = 3, nrow = 1, align = "hv")

figure
```

[image]

I would like to add a legend which represents the two colours (red/orange) with their labels (e.g. red = "Label 1", orange = "Label 2". How can I do this?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a reproducible example including data? It may help if Occam's razor were applied to the problem: simplify the example to two facets so that possible solutions could be tested and verified.

Comment: I will try and come up with a reprex, but I am not sure if faceting will work as I have done a lot of manual editing for each graph (I manually specified which bars to colour and which post-hoc comparisons to display, the heights and order of the significance value annotations etc) so it is easier to treat them as separate graphs and then bring everything together in ggarrange at the end.

Comment: @Peter I updated the question to include some example data and reproducible code :)

Comment: Your question is quite long, and difficult to read. To your statement about aesthetics... your bar color (I think you meant fill) is *very much* part of your graph aesthetic. In fact, color is one of the most important graph aesthetics. If it doesn't have meaning, leave it. But yours has ("label"). Conceptually, you will get the legends if you don't turn your legend off. I'd use {patchwork} to combine your plot, then you will be able to merge the legends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from pretty, but you need to map a separate variable to fill if you want the fill to be independent of the `dv_#` values.

Adjust labels as required.

The process would benefit from use of functions as there is so much repetition, but that is really separate issue.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) #  melt
library(rstatix) #  wilcox_test
library(ggpubr) #  stat_pvalue_manual
library(dplyr) # slice

set.seed(1234)
id <- rep(1:50, each = 3)
stimuli <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 1, times = 50)
dv_1 <- rnorm(150, mean = 2, sd = 0.7)
dv_2 <- rnorm(150, mean = 4, sd = 1.5)
dv_3 <- rnorm(150, mean = 7.5, sd = 1)


simdat <- data.frame(id, stimuli, dv_1, dv_2, dv_3)

#Stimuli A
dat_stimuli_a <- subset(simdat, stimuli == "a")

melt_a <- melt(dat_stimuli_a, id.vars = "id", measure.vars = c("dv_1", "dv_2", "dv_3"))

pwc_a <- melt_a %>%
  wilcox_test(value ~ variable, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "holm", detailed = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1:2)
# add label variable for simulation a
melt_a <- 
  melt_a %>% 
  mutate(label = if_else(variable == "dv_1", "label_1", "label_2"))

gg_a <- ggplot(melt_a, aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", width = 0.75, aes(fill = label)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="black", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc_a, label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.02, step.increase = 0.05, hide.ns = TRUE, y.position = c(7, 8), label.size = 3) +
  ggtitle("Stimuli A") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1), labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), limits = c(-0, 10)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=10)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25))

gg_a <- gg_a + scale_fill_manual(values = c("label_1" = "#9E0142", "label_2" = "#FDAE61")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")


#Stimuli B
dat_stimuli_b <- subset(simdat, stimuli == "b")

melt_b <- melt(dat_stimuli_b, id.vars = "id", measure.vars = c("dv_1", "dv_2", "dv_3"))

pwc_b <- melt_b %>%
  wilcox_test(value ~ variable, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "holm", detailed = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1, 3)
# add label variable for simulation b
melt_b <- 
  melt_b %>% 
  mutate(label = if_else(variable == "dv_2", "label_1", "label_2"))

gg_b <- ggplot(melt_b, aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", width = 0.75, aes(fill = label)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="black", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc_b, label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.02, step.increase = 0.05, hide.ns = TRUE, y.position = c(7, 8), label.size = 3) +
  ggtitle("Stimuli B") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1), labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), limits = c(-0, 10)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=10)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=10, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.25))

gg_b <- gg_b + scale_fill_manual(values = c("label_1" = "#9E0142", "label_2" = "#FDAE61")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")



ggarrange(gg_a, gg_b, ncol = 2, nrow = 1, align = "hv",
           common.legend = TRUE,
           legend = "bottom")
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).

#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).

#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for this! How can I edit the syntax so that I can colour multiple bars? I assume it is somewhere in the ```melt_a <- 
  melt_a %>% 
  mutate(label = if_else(variable == "dv_1", "label_1", "label_2"))``` section but I can't quite figure it out

Comment: If you have more than two colours for fill iotuibs then it would be simpler to use `dplyr::case_when` rather than nested `if_else`; if you are not familiar with this then check out the documentation `?case_when`; the syntax would probably be something along these lines within the call to mutate: `label = case_when(variable == "dv_1" ~ "red",   variable == "dv_2" | variable == "dv_3" ~ "green",   variable == "dv_4" ~ "yellow", TRUE ~ "black"`